# for loop with array in batch file with replacing a string variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to copy the file over network.

first i am mapping the drive using `NET`command and than copy file using `xcopy`.

follwing batch file works without any problem

```
    net use T: \\192.168.170.239\D /user:User1 PASSWROD
    set source=T:\backup
    set destination=D:\backup\
    xcopy %source% %destination% /y
    net use T: /delete 
    TIMEOUT 5
```

I would like to replace the static IP `'192.168.170.239'` and make any array of ip as below and replace the `netuse` command  in a loop.

```
@echo off 
set obj[0]=192.168.170.239
set obj[1]=192.168.170.240
set obj[2]=192.168.170.241
set obj[3]=192.168.170.242
```

I have treid the following but didn't work

```
 @echo off
set len=2
set obj[0]=192.168.170.239
set obj[1]=192.168.170.240


set i=0
:loop
if %i% equ %len% goto :eof
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%j in (`set obj[%i%]`) do (

net use T: \\%%j\D /user:User1 Password
TIMEOUT 10
set source=T:\Autobackup
set destination=D:\Autobackup\
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
net use T: /delete 
TIMEOUT 10

)
set /a i=%i%+1
goto loop
```

It works for the second ip but not for the first ip.

Comment: No error messages? Also, what's up with `set source=T:\backup` and `set source=T:\Autobackup` in your examples?

Comment: There is no need to set a variable `len` that defines the number of (pseudo-)array elements, since `set obj[` returns all elements, which you could count or loop through...

Comment: I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) about array management in Batch files...

Comment: if i want to create another arrary, for all differnt ip the destination folder is different how can i change the `Set "destination=D:\Autobackup\"` to `Set "destination=D:\Autobackup\Folder[0]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be looking at a structure more like this:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Undefine any existing variables beginning with obj[
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set obj[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A=" 

Rem Define your IP list
Set "obj[0]=192.168.170.239"
Set "obj[1]=192.168.170.240"
Set "obj[2]=192.168.170.241"
Set "obj[3]=192.168.170.242"

Rem Define your Map Source and Destination
Set "map=T:"
Set "source=%map%\Autobackup"
Set "destination=D:\Autobackup\"

Rem Loop through the IP list
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set obj[ 2^>Nul') Do (

    Rem Make sure that %map% is not currently mapped
    Net Use %map% /Delete 2>Nul

    Rem Map the share
    Net Use %map% \\%%B\D /User:User1 Password

    Rem Perform the required operation
    XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /Y

    Rem Delete the mapped share
    Net Use %map% /Delete 
)
```

Comment: I have tried but it didn't map the drive. i have put echo command after net use command  `echo %%A ` it returns `obj[0]` not the ip address

Comment: it works without any problem. I am glad if you can explain a  **two foor loop**  with ` %%A and %%B `

Comment: @Tarun.P, I don't see two for loops, There is only one. `%%A` and `%%B` tokens belong to the same loop, delimited by equal sign(`=`). `set obj[` returns list of variables which begins with `obj[`. ex: in `obj[3]=192.168.170.241` the first token `%%A` is `obj[3]` and the second token `%%B` is `192.168.170.241`

Comment: thanks for the info but i don't know why i am unable to understand this loop. Anyway can you help me with this...if i want to create another arrary, for all differnt ip the destination folder is different how can i change the Set "destination=D:\Autobackup\" to Set "destination=D:\Autobackup\Folder[0]"

Comment: @Tarun.P, if you have a new question, then please post it as such. An answer here isn't an open invitation to lifetime support for any and all future modifications or requirement changes.

Comment: @Compo I have created a new post. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266265/create-two-foor-loop-for-two-differnt-array-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

Compo's answer is good. Another way to construct the loop follows. It does not use an "array" of variables. I find this easier to edit and understand.

```
SET IPLIST=^
192.168.170.239 ^
192.168.170.240 ^
192.168.170.241 ^
192.168.170.242

FOR %%a IN (%IPLIST%) DO (
    ECHO %%a
)
```